# Problem Filtering Entities With "Not compatible with jpaMetamodelFiltering"

Tags: jhipster

I am new to using Jhipster, I generated a gateway application in which I am trying to create entities that allow filtering as indicated in https://www.jhipster.tech/entities-filtering/

My JDL application looks like this:

```
  application {
  config {
    baseName Appcommun,
    applicationType gateway,
    packageName co.appcommunity.gateway,
    serviceDiscoveryType eureka,
    authenticationType jwt,
    databaseType sql,
    devDatabaseType h2Disk,
    prodDatabaseType mysql,
    cacheProvider hazelcast,
    buildTool maven,
    clientFramework angularX,
    enableTranslation true,
    nativeLanguage es,
    languages [es, en],
    testFrameworks [protractor]
  }
  entities *

}



entity Community {
  name String required unique,
  description String,
  code String required unique,
  location String,
  address String required,
  logo String
}

dto * with mapstruct
filter Community
service * with serviceClass
```

When I run the Jhipster jdl jdlfile.jdl
You can see the following messages:

> info: The filter option is set for Community, the 'serviceClass' value for the 'service' is gonna be set for this entity if no other value has been set.

> WARNING! Not compatible with jpaMetamodelFiltering, disabling

Generated Entity JSON looks like:

```
  {
  "name": "Community",
  "fields": [
    {
      "fieldName": "name",
      "fieldType": "String",
      "fieldValidateRules": ["required", "unique"]
    },
    {
      "fieldName": "description",
      "fieldType": "String"
    }
  ],
  "relationships": [],
  "entityTableName": "community",
  "dto": "mapstruct",
  "pagination": "no",
  "service": "serviceClass",
  "jpaMetamodelFiltering": false,
  "fluentMethods": true,
  "readOnly": false,
  "embedded": false,
  "applications": ["easycommuniy"],
  "databaseType": "sql",
  "changelogDate": "20210603013758"
}
```

No filter service was generated.

Can any body say me what I'm doing wrong?

Can someone give me some hints? What am I doing wrong?

I tried to put jpaMetamodelFiltering": true, and regenerate the entity with the same result.

Thanks.

Comment: I know that entity filtering is not compatible with Reactive, see https://github.com/jhipster/generator-jhipster/issues/14616 I'm not sure if it impacts gateway as well. You should open a github issue